# How to close all tabs and windows but keep vim open

Tags: vim

The title says it: How can I quickly close everything but keep vim open (show the starting view again)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform window and tab operations using the [`windo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:windo) and [`tabdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tabdo) commmands (though I didn't use these in the provided mapping below)

To show the starting view again, run `:intro`:

Here is a little mapping to accomplish your original question that seemed to work best for me:

```
" this will fail if there are unsaved changes
function! StartOver()
  new     " open a new, empty split
  only    " close other windows
  tabonly " close other tabs
  intro   " show opening screen
endfunction
nnoremap <F4> :call StartOver()<CR>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Just one cosmetical issue: Using `intro` waits for a key press of `CR` and therefore does not exactly behave as a brand new vim instance. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Remo, I also noticed that and wished it was more exact to how Vim behaves when it's first opened. After looking through `:help :intro` I didn't see any additional options to improve this however...

Comment: It should be noted that with `'hidden'` active that the buffers will still be open.

Comment: What I ended up with is `bufdo bd`, as this also closes all buffers and thus clears them from the buffer list.